# Can I get a slug automatically added to _path urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my routes I have:

`match "feed/:event_id/:event_description", to: 'feed#event', :as => :event_feed, via: :get`

I have this to help with SEO. The `event_description` just generates a 'slug' that I *hope* helps with SEO.

I call this route, for example in a view with

`event_feed_path(event_id: post.event.id, event_description: post.event.url_description_fragment`

Is there a way to get `event_description` auto-magically just included so that I can write the less verbose `event_feed_path(event_id: post.event.id)`

`event_description` is a column in `Event` model and it is ALWAYS included with event_feed_path... can rails just add this in for me without me explicitly adding it?

Thanks

For no good reason I do not want to use the friendly-url gem, because (for no good reason) I don't want my url to be `/feed/17635-Cardinals-vs-Giants-on-July-30-2016`

I prefer `/feed/17635/Cardinals-vs-Giants-on-July-30-2016` which has a backslash and not a '-' separating the SEO friendly text

Comment: I think you'd need to write your own helper where you'd pass in the `post` object and build out the path from there. The auto-generated `_path` helpers stay flexible in this area without trying to do too much magic.

Comment: Be careful about having the `id` as a separate folder in the URL. What happens if the user browses to `/feed/17635` instead of `/feed/17635/Cardinals-vs-Giants-on-July-30-2016`? Perhaps redirect that to the slugged version?

Comment: Sure I could redirect. In fact I should for "short" url's to share. That is easy enough. I just feel there must be a way to get this friendly text auto-magically added. I mean I do it everytime. Do I really need to specifically add it every time I use this path helper?

Comment: That's what I said. Yes, if you want to use the built-in `_path` helper, you need to manually fill in the placeholders with their values. It would be impossible for Rails to know which object(s) each placeholder matches, as is the case that you sometimes end up passing in multiple objects.

Comment: If it helps you any, you don't need to include the key names when calling the helper. You can do this: `event_feed_path(post.event, post.event.url_description_fragment)`

Comment: That is interesting. How does it know which is which? Is it because it is NOT a hash... and therefore just goes from left to right?

Comment: Yes, it goes from left to right.

Comment: And ah yes I guess I would just need to create my own helper. Would this slow things down at all?

Comment: Not that what I am doing is THAT big a deal... I just felt it wasn't very 'dry'

Comment: No, I don't believe it would slow things down in any significant way.